# FragmentStatePageAdapter cache, how do I reference old fragments after activity recreated? (for ex - landscape mode)

Tags: java, android, caching, landscape, fragmentstatepageradapter

In my app I got a ViewPager which is showing 3 fragments in a swipe views layout.
If the activity is recreated (for example, if I go to landscape mode) I can't get a reference to the fragments anymore.

This is my Adapter

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    public static final String FRAGMENT_MAP = "fragmentMap";
    private SparseArray<MyFragment> myFragmentMap = new SparseArray<MyFragment>();

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm){
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
            String nameOfTab = actionBar.getTabAt(arg0).getText().toString();
            ArrayList<VideoBookmark> listOfFragment = myBookmarkManager.getList(nameOfTab);
        args.putParcelableArrayList(MyFragment.ARG_LIST, listOfFragment);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        myFragmentMap.put(arg0, fragment);

        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    //return mytabs.size()???
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_OF_TABS;
    }

    public void destroyItem (ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        myFragmentMap.remove(position);
    }

    public Fragment getFragment(int key) {
        return myFragmentMap.get(key);
    }

    public SparseArray<MyFragment> getFragmentMap(){
        return myFragmentMap;
    }

    public void setNewFragmentMap(SparseArray<MyFragment> newMap){
        myFragmentMap = newMap;
    }

}
```

I get null pointer exception in this line

```
//get current fragment
    int index = myViewPager.getCurrentItem();
    Fragment fragment = myTabsPagerAdapter.getFragment(index);

    EditText title = (EditText) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.new_title);
```

I checked, this is happening because the getItem method is not called, so I guess the adapter reuses old fragments in some way, but how can I access this fragments cache to get my old fragments and to be able to use the findViewById method?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

getFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag() // <<-- if you are managing fragments dynamically
getFragmentManager.findFragmentById() // <<-- if you are using <fragment> in the layout file.

Comment: Thankyou,by the way as you can see in my getItem method I didn't use transactions, so I didn't assigned tags. I found on the web this method:
 `public Fragment findFragmentByPosition(int position) {
    FragmentPagerAdapter fragmentPagerAdapter = getFragmentPagerAdapter();
    return getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(
            "android:switcher:" + getViewPager().getId() + ":"
                    + fragmentPagerAdapter.getItemId(position));
}`
but fragmentstatepageradapter doesn't have the getItemId(position) method, so how can I manage to find fragments by tag?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure of this, but I solved calling `instantiateItem(viewpager, position)` to get the fragment at the given position. If I got it right this method returns the fragment at the given position if it exists, if not it creates another one (I'm guessing it calls `getItem()`)